# Extract the characters before last colon

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I need to extract the characters before last colon `:` and also remove the square brackets `[]` in the last line.
My file structure is

```
256.XXX.XXX.X:20234
214.XXX.XXX.X:7249
[2200:XXXX:XXXX:XXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX]:46288
```

I need output file as in the form of:

```
256.XXX.XXX.X
214.XXX.XXX.X
2200:XXXX:XXXX:XXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX
```

Comment: In your output, you also remove the `[ ]`, but you don't mention it

Comment: Ok I edited my answer to remove brackets...

Comment: Is that `netstat` result which contains IP and port?

Answer (score 10):

Remove everything after the last colon, and then any brackets left anywhere:

```
sed 's/:[^:]*$//; s/[][]//g'
```

Or

```
sed 's/\(.*\):.*/\1/; s/[][]//g'
```

(here using the fact that  the first `.*` will be greedy and swallow as many `:`s as possible).

Comment: The `[ ]` also need to be removed, it seems

Comment: @Philippos, OK, I'm with you now. Thanks. I've edited it  in.

Comment: Thanks everyone. This is working

Comment: `[][]` is something of a regex corner-case and might warrant some explaining.

Answer (score 3):

This will extract all characters before last 'colon' and remove the brackets [  ] as the example you give.

```
rev <yourfile.txt | cut -d: -f2- | rev | tr -d '[]'
```

Replace yourfile.txt by your file name or remove the word `<yourfile.txt` to read the standard output.

Comment: Note that `rev` is not a  standard (POSIX) command (comes from plan9, GNU has one as well). That unquoted `[]` will cause an error in `csh` or `zsh`.

Comment: Right I corrected it with quotes. In practice there are some unixes without rev or even some busybox environment that does not have it?

Comment: There's none on Solaris. BSDs, GNU, busybox, AIX and HPUX seem to all have one.

Answer (score 2):

`awk -F: '{OFS=":"; NF--; print $0}' $file`

or

`cat file | awk -F: '{OFS=":"; NF--; print $0}'`

which breaks down as:

- `-F:` set the input field separator to `:`
- `OFS=":"` set the output field separator to `:`
- `NF--` reduce the Number of Fields by 1 (get rid of the last field)
- `print $0` print the remaining records, separated by the OFS (`:`) character.

**Update** to also remove the square brackets:

`awk -F: '{OFS=":"; NF--; gsub(/\[|\]/, ""); print $0}' $file`

- added `gsub(/\[|\]/, "")1` which performs a global substitution on the square brackets, replacing them with nothing, and returning the substituted string.

Answer (score 2):

Shell only:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    tmp=${line%:*}               # remove last colon and following chars
    tmp=${tmp#"["}               # remove leading open bracket
    result=${tmp%"]"}            # remove trailing close bracket
    printf "%s\n" "$result"
done < file
```

Comment: I don't know why but I always love this kind of solutions... Just because it does run with a minimal tools environment.

Comment: And [I always cringe at them](/q/169716). Here, you can also add a portability dimension as those `${tmp#[}` won't work with ksh93 or zsh.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas In true I agree with you in security / reliability terms. But I think you understand my point of view too.

Comment: Seems to work fine with ksh "version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01". I don't have an older version to test with.

Comment: `ksh -c 'tmp=${tmp#[}'` gives a syntax error with ksh93u+, but `tmp=anything ksh -c 'tmp=${tmp#[}'` doesn't. Looks like a bug. In any case, `[` being a wildcard operator is better quoted. `tmp=${tmp#"["}` works OK in any POSIX-like shell. You'd want to replace `echo` with `printf '%s\n'` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Command:

```
awk -F ":" 'OFS=":"{$NF="";print $0}' filename | sed "s/:$//g"| sed "s/^\[//g"|sed "s/\]//g"
```

output

```
256.XXX.XXX.X
214.XXX.XXX.X
2200:XXXX:XXXX:XXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX
```

Comment: This doesn’t seem any better than Tim Kennedy’s existing answer. For future reference, if you’re using AWK, you don’t need `sed` too...